# Trouble with module "node compare"

Tags: entities, nodes

I have installed the module [node compare](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_compare). You can compare fields of every node type with this module. I selected about 19 fields to the comparison table but only twelve appear. I posted an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2314391) but the maintainer has no time to help me. As I am no coder I am having some a hard time figuring this out.

I know that this is not a easy question but I don't see any other chance to get this problem solved. Does anyone has a advice what I can do? Or maybe somebody also uses the module and can share some experiences?

Thomas.

Comment: As the module maintainer also remarks in the issue queue, it is difficult to reproduce this error. You are simply not providing enough information. Which 7 fields do not appear? Do they show up on normal node view? Do you have any permissions modules installed? etc.

Comment: Well, after he told me that he can't reproduce the bug I provided him more information and asked if an export of my view would help. For example I told that the field "bundesland" appears when I add eight fields but it dissapears when I add more than ten. In my opinion he just has no time. So am I lost here? :-(